# How can I get a variable into a argument?

Tags: discord.js

I have the following code :

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

var number = command.length - 1;
var times = args[number ***Here I want the last position of the user input***];
```

If you write an command in a text channel, the last argument from the user input should get into the times variable. Here's one example: the user writes '!test some random text 3' and the last argument (in this case 3) should get into a varable. Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `args.length - 1` so in your case `var times = args[args.length - 1]`